# 2000's spooky show with a group of teens telling spooky stories in the woods

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for a TV show I saw part of when I was a kid (circa 2003). I saw the show in Canada (probably an American show, though). It was in English. It looked contemporary.

A group of teens are telling each other spooky stories (in the woods?). We flash back to the teens in a dark house late at night. They are pursued by a glowing dog. Two girls try to close a door, but the dog's glow shines through the cracks.

This show scared me so much. I would like to re-watch it to process my trauma.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is probably [*Are You Afraid of the Dark?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_You_Afraid_of_the_Dark%3F), a Canadian horror-anthology series for teens where the framing device was a group of kids who met in the woods to tell each other creepy stories.

The 'flashback' you mention would be the show cutting from the group to the story being told.

Comment: https://areyouafraidofthedark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Mystical_Mirror perhaps?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this show is being rebooted as a miniseries this month. Might be of interest to OP.

Comment: As soon as I read the title of this in the HNQ bar I knew it was AYAOTD. I watched that show so much when I was a kid.

Comment: I was thinking either this or Goosebumps, but I don't remember if that had the campfire framing device...

Comment: Submitted for the approval of the Midnight Society, I call this story... :)

Comment: I think this is definitely Are You Afraid of the Dark, but I don't think it was the mirror episode. I watched it and it didn't look right. I'll keep looking, and if no one can find the exact episode I'll mark this as answered. Thank you!

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Too soon man...

Comment: @Tesserae maybe [*The Tale of the Hungry Hounds*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0514423/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl#synopsis)?